# Reduce or remove search engine ranking for mirrored (via RSS) content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have a site which publishes blog articles.

The site has an RSS feed and the RSS feed is consumed by a support-ticket system:

*This is necessary because some users only visit the support site and I want them to see the latest news. However ...*

Google prioritizes links on the support site *over* the main site. I want to prioritize the main site (in fact, ignore RSS generated news articles on the support site) in search engines.

**Example:**

Google "scichart upgrade from v3"

[image]

I want the article on the main site to come up in google, but instead the article on the support site comes up first.

I have google webmaster tools set up + FTP access to both sites. How can I tell Google to ignore anything that starts with `http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/News/` ?

Comment: There two basic options: one, use a canonical tag from the duplicate page to the original; two, noindex the duplicate page. There are other options, however, these seem to make the most sense.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that! The duplicates are generated by a support desk but we have access to the source. Meta / NoIndex might be a really really simple solution. I'm going to try it! PS: Why not create an answer for the +vote?

Comment: Use robots.txt with `Dissalow` rule for your support links, and `rel="nofollow` attribute for the links in your site that point to your support section

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [meta rel link canonical tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on the duplicate pages syndicated from the RSS feeds.

The page on your support site should have tag that looks like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/news/news-story.html" />
```

That points the article back to the original.   When Googlebot sees this tag, it will know that the two pages are duplicate and that you would prefer to have the main one indexed because you have marked it as canonical.